# How I can check if the element of a list is the last?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm trying to do something like:

```
{"semaforo":"icbc"},{"semaforo":"pepito"}
```

I have the following code:

```
for (Iterator it = semaforosMiddleware.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    KeyMapMediciones semaforoMiddleware = (KeyMapMediciones) it.next();
    jsonFamilias.append("{\"semaforo\":\"" + semaforoMiddleware.getAplicacion() + "\"}");
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        jsonFamilias.append(",");
    }
}
```

But I get output like:

```
{"semaforo":"icbc"},{"semaforo":"pepito"},
```

I don't want the final comma (",") after the last element. What can I do?

Comment: Have a look at [Guava's Joiner](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted works fine. Here's a simplified runnable example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args){

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("one");
        list.add("two");
        list.add("three");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (Iterator<String> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            String element = it.next();
            sb.append(element);
            if(it.hasNext()){
                sb.append(", ");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString()); //prints: one, two, three

    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The nicest and simplest trick I learned on this site:

```
String separator = "";
for (String s : coll) {
   buf.append(separator).append(s);
   separator = ",";
}
```

Comment: Haha I love it. Stupid and elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Find below a Java 8 solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("one");
    list.add("two");
    list.add("three");

    String toString = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    System.out.println("toString = " + toString);
}
```

**output**

```
toString = one, two, three
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the first element instead (i.e. add a comma before each element except the first element) :

```
boolean first = true;
for (Iterator it = semaforosMiddleware.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    if(!first){
        jsonFamilias.append(",");
    } else {
        first = false;
    }
    KeyMapMediciones semaforoMiddleware = (KeyMapMediciones) it.next();
    jsonFamilias.append("{\"semaforo\":\"" + semaforoMiddleware.getAplicacion() + "\"}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also do:

```
String jsonFamilias = semaforosMiddleware.stream()
                        .map(s -> "{\"semaforo\":\"" + s.getAplicacion() + "\"}")
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: possible in for Java8+

Comment: Absolutely. People should use it. This snippet is so much cleaner

Comment: okay, Actually its not just clean code rather people have some other serious issues like supporting application made in previous version

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
stringBuilder.append(Joiner.on(", ").join(semaforosMiddleware));
String resultString = stringBuilder.toString();
```

The use of a Joiner makes these scenarios much easier to handle.